# What does my min-sdk version need to be in order to use GoogleApiAvailability?

Tags: android

I'm replacing GooglePlayServicesUtil with GoogleApiAvailability and want to know if I need a certain min SDK.  Right now my min-sdk is 21. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

states: *"The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher."*

So that's 17 or higher